# Accessing MMU/TLB at boot on Microblaze

Tags: assembly, memory-management, tlb, microblaze

I am seeking to set up the TLB on a Microblaze (actually simulated on OVP), and have `C_USE_MMU` set to `3`.

This is my boot code:

```
    .global _start
    .section .vectors.reset, "ax"
    .align 2
    .ent _start
    .type _start, @function

_start:
    brai    _actualstart
    .end _start

....

    .section .text
    .global _actualstart
    .align 4
    .ent _actualstart
    .type _actualstart, @function

 _actualstart:
    mfs r1, rmsr
    nop
    ori r1, r1, 0x00040000
    mts rmsr, r1
    nop

    addik   r3, r0, 0x3F    /* Microblaze TLB has 64 entries */
_zeroouttlb:
    mts rtlbx, r3
    mts rtlbhi, r0
    mts rtlblo, r0
    bgtid   r3, _zeroouttlb /* Uses delay slot */
    addik   r3, r3, -1
```

The line below updates `r1` to `0x00040000` as you would expect:

```
ori r1, r1, 0x00040000
```

But on the next line:

```
mts rmsr, r1
```

The value of `msr` is left unchanged and so the code goes on to fail on:

```
mts rtlbhi, r0
```

With:

```
Fatal (MB_TLB) Attempting Write to TLBHI when no MMU available
```

(As `msr` has not been updated it still reads `0x00000000` so the processor is correct in assessing there is no MMU support available).

Why won't my code update the `msr`?

Comment: Sounds like the simulator simply doesn't attempt to emulate MMU.  So the MSR bit can't change either.

Comment: Don't think that's correct as the simulator can run Linux with MMU AIUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting wrong bit. Many reference guides describing BigEndian architecture assume that bit #31 is 2^0 and bit #0 is 2^31. MicroBlaze manual is one of those using this confusing notation.

In your case if you want to set bit VM (BigEndian bit 18) you need to set `msr` to  `0x00002000` or `1 << (31-18)`.

So basically changing line:

```
ori r1, r1, 0x00002000
mts rmsr, r1
nop
```

should make everything work.

Comment: Thanks, will test later - but surely you are setting bit 13 there in big endian unless the assembler is reversing the bit order. I'm a bit confused :)

Comment: ah, I see what you mean - the manual has got this all back to front. That is pretty bloody unhelpful.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately many BigEndian documents tend to number bits in reverse order, including TCP/IP headers even on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header). This tradition is really frustrating and brings a lot of confusion. Needless to say, once you switch your MicroBlaze to LittleEndian, this bit will remain the same `0x00002000`. It's just the documentation.

Comment: Well it looks like your Microblaze system (or emulator) does not have MMU support as it says. Writing to `TLBHI/LO` does not require VM bit to be set in `rmsr`. Its actually opposite, those registers are accessed with VM=0 and only when everything is set up virtual mode is turned on. Please check your configuration or emulator options. You can also check MB version register `PVR0` to see what Microblaze thinks of its configuration.

Comment: No, it was me getting mixed up. I have to set the TLB up before I poke at the MSR but otherwise your answer seems to have been correct.